# Fetching values from multiple tables in different columns

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g

I need to fetch data from multiple tables but with some scenarios here are test scripts to re-create the problem

```
create table sub_test (sub_id number);

create table sub_svc_test (sub_id number, sub_svc_id number);

create table sub_svc_parm_test (sub_svc_id number, parm_id number, val varchar2(20) );

insert into sub_test values (100);
insert into sub_test values (101);
insert into sub_test values (102);

insert into sub_svc_test values (100,1001);
insert into sub_svc_test values (100,1002);
insert into sub_svc_test values (101,1005);
insert into sub_svc_test values (101,1006);
insert into sub_svc_test values (101,1007);
insert into sub_svc_test values (102,1009);
insert into sub_svc_test values (102,1010);

insert into sub_svc_parm_test values (1001, 51, 'test_id');
insert into sub_svc_parm_test values (1001, 53, 'no');
insert into sub_svc_parm_test values (1002, 54, 'max');
insert into sub_svc_parm_test values (1005, 51, 'test_id');
insert into sub_svc_parm_test values (1007, 51, 'test_id');
insert into sub_svc_parm_test values (1007, 54, 'min');
```

I need to fetch values from sub_svc_parm_test table for VAL column for a particular parm_id such that

```
select * from sub_svc_test ss, sub_svc_parm_test ssp
where ss.sub_svc_id = ssp.sub_svc_id and parm_id = 51;
```

this query will give me the VAL for 51 parm_id now i need to craete a view which will show me the VAL for parm_id 51, 54 but in differnet column like

```
select ssp.val, ssp1.val
from sub_svc_test ss, sub_svc_parm_test ssp, sub_svc_test ss1,
     sub_svc_parm_test ssp1
where ss.sub_svc_id = ssp.sub_svc_id
  and ssp.parm_id = 51
  and ssp1.parm_id  = 54
  and ss1.sub_svc_id = ssp1.sub_svc_id;
```

This query will give me output but also it performs cross joins as i have not join the sub_svc_test ss, and sub_svc_test ss1 so it gives me 6 rows 2*3
but the requirement is that it should show me MAX rows of any column in our case it is first column (3 rows) and the remaining row which do not have data can contain any string or simply null in it like

```
VAL             VAL_1
--------------     -------------             
test_id         max
test_id         min
test_id         null
```

i am using ----
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production

Please ask for any clarification

Thanks

Comment: I suspect that your problems would go away if you learned to use proper explicit `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: @Gordon--i know that these joins are not perfect but when i join them it gives me no result as we can see that the sub_svc_id is different for parm_id i want to fetch..And also EXPLICIT JOIN  you mean outer join?

Comment: You can remove the two `sub_svc_test` completely from your query, as you are only dealing with `sub_svc_parm_test` actually. So you cross join (i.e. combine) all its 51 records with all its 54 records. But I don't understand what you are actually trying to achieve. Can you give some sample data and desired output?

Comment: Yes here we require data only from SUB_SVC_PARM_TEST but still we need SUB_SVC_TEST table as we need to check if the subscriber service are those which we need and it has corresponding value in the SUB_SVC_PARM_TEST table. Actually in real database these tables are very huge and contains more columns so i can not write the exact table structure here

Answer (score 0):

So you actually want to perform two separate selects and display them next to each other.

Maybe something like this could work:

```
select val, val1 from (
  (select rownum as r, val as val from sub_svc_parm_test ssp1 where parm_id = 51) 
  full outer join 
  (select rownum as r1, val as val1 from sub_svc_parm_test ssp2 where parm_id = 54)
  on r = r1
)
```

Comment: but you have not consider the sub_svc_id in the query actually the database model is like first i have a sub_id in which i can have multiple sub_svc_id (for each service that the SUB have). And the parm_id is derived from another table which i have not mention here to make it simple. So we have to make sure the VAL we are fetching here only belongs to those sub_svc_id which have a particular Service on it and the corresponding VAL. But still your QUERY is helpful i will try to use it in my requirement.

Comment: You should add the rest to both subqueries. This bloats the SQL to twice the size and makes it harder to maintain (unless you put the identical parts in a view), but performance is better than the alternative if the tables are large.